# What is the purpose of file descriptors?

Tags: c, fopen, file-descriptor

My understanding is that both `fopen()` and `open()` can be used to open files. `open()` returns a file descriptor. But they should be equivalent in terms of get a file for writing or reading. What is the purpose of definining the file descriptors? It is not clear from the wiki page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Answer (score 2):

`fopen` returns a `FILE *` which is a wrapper around the file descriptor (I will ignore the "this is not required by the specification" aspect here, as I am not aware of an implementation that does not do this). At a high level, it looks like this:

```
application --FILE *--> libc --file descriptor--> kernel
```

Shells operate directly on file descriptors mainly because they are executing other programs, and you cannot modify the other program's `FILE *` objects. However, you are able to modify other program's file descriptors using the `dup` syscall at startup (i.e. between `fork` and `exec`). For example:

```
/bin/cat > foo.txt
```

This tells the shell to execute the `/bin/cat` program, but first redirect stdout (file descriptor #1) to a file that it opens. This is implemented as (pseudocode):

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    int fd = open("foo.txt");
    dup2(fd, 1);
    exec("/bin/cat");
}
```

The closest thing you can do with `FILE *` is calling `freopen`, but this is not persisted when using `exec` unlike file descriptors.

But why do we need `FILE *` at all then, if it's just a wrapper around a file descriptor? One main benefit is having a readahead buffer. For example, consider `fgets`. This will eventually call the `read` syscall on the file descriptor associated with the `FILE *` that you pass in. But how does it know how much to read? The kernel has no option to say "give me one line" (line-buffered ttys aside). If you read more than one line in the first `read`, the next time you call `fgets` you might only get part of the next line, since the kernel has already given you the first part in the previous `read` syscall. The other option would be calling `read` one character at a time, which is horrible for performance.

So what does libc do? It reads a bunch of characters at once, then stores the extra characters in an internal buffer on the `FILE *` object. The next time you call `fgets`, it is able to use the internal buffer. This buffer is also shared with functions like `fread`, so you can interleave calls to `fgets` and `fread` without losing data.

Comment: Mostly true, though `FILE`s are not necessarily buffered.  But none of this really answers the question posed.  POSIX *could* have defined most everything related to file descriptors in terms of (pointers to) `FILE` objects instead.  Observing that it didn't does not explain *why* it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The two function at different levels:

- `open()` is a lower-level, POSIX function to open a file. It returns a distinct integer to identify, and enable access to, the file opened. This integer is a *file descriptor.*
- `fopen()` is a higher-level, portable, C standard-library function to open a file.

On a POSIX system, the portable `fopen()` probably calls the nonportable `open()`, but this is an implementation detail.

When in doubt, prefer `fopen()`.

For more information, on a Linux system, `man 2 read`. The POSIX `read()` function reads data via the file descriptor returned by `open()`.

Comment: Shells primarily use file descriptors. How do they make it portable?

Comment: As far as I know, if the system supports a POSIX-based shell like Bash—and as far as I know just about everything but MS Windows does support it, and maybe Windows too these days—then the system would support POSIX. Ergo, `open()` would be portable to the extent to which POSIX is portable. However, it would not be portable in the sense of being part of the library every standard, hosted C installation is required to provide. Does this answer your question?

Comment: One can do binary I/O via the `fread()` and `fwrite()` functions of the C standard library (using a `FILE *` obtained from `fopen()`).  Plus, that way you get buffered I/O automatically if you want it.  Can you be more specific about why you say file descriptor-based I/O is better than stream I/O for such tasks?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You have taught me something I had not known. I had been using `open()` for that purpose for 20 years. In view of your advice, I have deleted the paragraph regarding binary and `fopen()`.